# Why Cypress not open modal page?

Tags: javascript, cypress

i'm doing some tests  and a need to click in a button and is to open a modal page, the click work but the modal page not appear, already used several commands and anything work...

My code:

```js
describe("Test Modal", () => {
  it("Modal open", () => {
    cy.get("span[name=teste]").
    contains("Send Email")
      .click({
        force: true
      })
// It was for modal to appear.
  })
})
```

Comment: If you don't use `force: true`, does it still click successfully, or does it throw an error? My best guess here is that the element you're clicking isn't the right element to trigger the modal, but I wouldn't know without seeing the HTML/Javascript of your application.

Comment: How do you know the click worked?

Comment: @eric99 Because i put a console.log and it not appear.

Comment: @JoshuaWade Yes, click successfully but the modal not appear. I put also a console.log, and saw that is the React Contextify.

Comment: @Jean Could you update your post with either the code you're working with or a smallest possible HTML/JS/Cypress code set that reproduces your issue? There's nothing inherently wrong with the Cypress code you posted, so the issue must be in how Cypress is interacting with your application code.

Comment: @JoshuaWade allright, i will update

Comment: I discovered with my modal that it needs a small `cy.wait()` after the click, because of transition effect on opening. Cypress is supposed to automatically wait by retrying the command following the click, but it is not always working.

Comment: How long does it take for the modal to open? There is a default wait time of about 5 seconds, but it can be increased by editing your project configuration settings.